# Why does the following code have no output?

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
import random
import time
def displayIntro():
    print('You are in a land full of dragons. You see a cave in front of you. In one cave, there is a dragon who will share his treasure with you. The other cave contains a dragon that will eat you on sight.')
```

Comment: Because you never call the method `displayIntro`. You need to add a new line (no indentation) with `displayIntro()`

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this... New user, new to python give him a nudge on how to ask questions

Comment: @L_Church People are not downvoting the user, but are estimating how useful this question will be to future readers. It doesn't look very useful - it's a trivial oversight. It can happen to everybody of course, but can happen for millions of different reasons, and is easy to fix by following one of the first few examples of any Python tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function

add

```
displayIntro()
```

to the end of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a function, made a print statement inside but you have never actually called the function. All you do to call it is just put type the name of it in the program.

Importantly, make sure you call the function BELOW the declaration because it's procedural

Comment: It has nothing to do with the programming style in this particular script being "procedural".

Comment: It's still a thing you need to remember as a noob. You don't see it everyday sure but it's nice to remember that you can't call above

Comment: Yes, but it has nothing to do with being procedural.

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter has no way to know that `displayIntro` is the method you want it to call. Imagine, that there could be 10 different top-level methods. The simplest fix is to just call the method in the main scope:

```
import random
import time
def displayIntro():
    print('You are in a land full of dragons. You see a cave in front of you. In one cave, there is a dragon who will share his treasure with you. The other cave contains a dragon that will eat you on sight.')

displayIntro()
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is Simple.
you have defined the function,but you have never called the function..
only when you call the function,the function will be executed..
So the code looks like this:

```
import random
import time

def displayIntro():
    print('You are in a land full of dragons. You see a cave in front of you. In 
           one cave, there is a dragon who will share his treasure with you. The 
           other cave contains a dragon that will eat you on sight.')

displayIntro()
```

You will be able to get the desired output.